# TextMate 2 and lost paths

Tags: paths, scripts, textmate

This is a recent development, and I'm not sure what I've changed to make this happen… other than setting `TM_SUPPORT_PATH` to `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared`.

I had to do that a month ago to get LaTeX files to compile (another mystery, since it previously compiled without issue). They seem to work fine now, but when I try to create italics (or bold, underline, etc.), TextMate spits back the error:

> `Failure running “Italic”.`
>
> `Italic: line 4: toggle_style.rb: command not found`

This same error occurs when I try to invoke other scripts contained in the LaTeX bundle (Tidy, anything invoking `texMate.py`). All of these seem to rely on `TM_SUPPORT_PATH` in the script, and yet none of these scripts resides within the `shared` directory… They're all in `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/bin`.

I could solve this problem by changing the path in all of the scripts to a `TM_LATEX_SUPPORT` path, or by moving or linking all of the scripts to the shared directory… but this doesn't seem like it should be necessary. Any ideas on what I may have broken?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Noted, I'll keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted this to the TextMate mailing list, and was informed that my issue was with TextMate, not any of the LaTeX stuff on my system. The solution was to disable the custom `TM_SUPPORT_PATH`, then reinstall the "Bundle Support" package for TextMate.